# make floated box under another

Tags: css, html

How can I make the blue box be directly under the red box without extra space?

```css
.div1 {
  background-color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;

}
.div2 {
  background-color:red;
  float:right;
  display:inline;
  height:20px;

}
.div3 {
  background-color:blue;
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  height:30px;
  
}
.box {width:50px;
clear:both;
}
```

```html
  <div class="div1 box">

  </div>

  <div class="div2 box">
  red
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="div3 box">
  blue
  </div>
```

Comment: Remove the <br />

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<br>` from your html:

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  height: 20px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1 box">
</div>

<div class="div2 box">
  red
</div>

<!-- remove this: <br> -->

<div class="div3 box">
  blue
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br />` tag. [See image of finished output or run code snippet] Like this:

```css
.div1 {
  background-color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;

}
.div2 {
  background-color:red;
  float:right;
  display:inline;
  height:20px;

}
.div3 {
  background-color:blue;
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  height:30px;
  
}
.box {width:50px;
clear:both;
}
```

```html
  <div class="div1 box">

  </div>

  <div class="div2 box">
  red
  </div>
  <div class="div3 box">
  blue
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: @Remix 2017 - The image you showed, is what this code outputs.